# Image under nav making links not clickable.

Tags: html, css

For some reason the links are not clickable unless it's in Internet Explorer. I tried giving it a smaller z-index and I even double check for any conflicts but I just can not get this to work. I'm sure it's because on the nav but I honestly have no idea how to work around that?

I have the code set as so:

```
    /* Navbar BG Big */
.image {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
    background-image: url(../images/headerbg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Navbar BG Small */
@media all and (max-width: 1200px) { 
.image {
    background-image: url(../images/spacer.gif);
} 
}

/* Logo Styles */
@media all and (max-width: 800px) { 
#big-logo {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -999;
}
}

@media all and (min-width: 800px) { 
#small-logo {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -998;
}
}

/* Small Nav */
@media all and (max-width: 900px) { 
nav ul {
    list-style-image: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: .5em;
    margin-left: .5em;
}
}

/* Big Nav */
@media all and (min-width: 900px) { 
nav ul {
    list-style-image: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    margin-top: .4em;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
}
}

.navtext:link, .navtext:visited {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    padding-right: 2em;
    font-style: normal;
}  

.navtext:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #00c4ff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

HTML

```
    <!-- logo & nav !-->
<div class="image">

    <nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="navtext">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="navtext">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="navtext">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="navtext">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="navtext">Product</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="navtext">Store</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="navtext">Support</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="navtext">Contact</a></li>        
</ul>
    <ul>
    <li>
<div id="spacer"></div>    
    <!-- big logo !-->
<img src="images/headerlogo.png" alt="ETV Software" id="big-logo" border="0"/>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>

    <!-- navdrop image here !-->
<img src="images/navdrop.png"/>   

    <!-- small logo !--> 
<img src="images/headerlogo.png" alt="Etv Software" id="small-logo" border="0"/> 

</div>
```

[JSFiddle of the code above](http://jsfiddle.net/M38ka/)

Comment: Do you have this on the web somewhere we can see it with the rest of its resources?

Comment: You are setting all `ul` that are descendant of `nav` to `position:absolute;`. The default behavior is to have them displayed from back to front in the order they are encountered. So the first `ul` (the links) will be underneath the second `ul` (the images).

Comment: That said, why don't you just use a css background image?

Comment: http://etvdomains.com/etvsite/index.html

I can not remove the absolute positioning because I am placing the text over an image.

Comment: @Shmiddty I can't use CSS for the background image because I want it to resize according to the resolution.

Comment: @angelaR You can do that with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of giving negative `z-index` to elements, try setting the `z-index: 1` for the `ul` you want on top.

http://jsfiddle.net/M38ka/1/

Comment: This solved the problem! You are a life saver, seriously, thank you!